# Current Activated Diode Switch

Tags: microcontroller, switches, diodes

Ok so here's my situation.

I have a custom board with a micro controller that has a 6 pin connector. If I plug in a device to the connector that requires power it should provide somewhere on the order of 200ma @3.7v (from my PSU) to said device. However it's possible (and expected) that the same connector might be used with another device that is sending power @5v and in that case I want to close the circuit and not have any flow in or out.

1) 3.7v -----> Out (To device requiring power)

2) 3.7v ----> X <---- 5Volt (powered device attached shut it all down)

What's the best circuit/solution for this? Some type of diode switch?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you could directly use a diode.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcGuwk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding how the diode will behave in this case but won't the 3.7v still feed into the 5volt device?

Comment: Current goes from high voltage to low. This means that the current wants to travel counterclockwise. The diode only passes current in the clockwise direction, so the left of the diode stays at 3.7V and the right stays at 5V. If you replace V2 with a load, you'll find that the current passes through. However, a diode has a forward voltage drop of about 0.7V, so the right of the diode would end up being at about 3V instead of 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

First I touhgt this should be possible with a MOSFET. You could use a P-Channel type which is wired to usually be conducting. If there is a +5V present on the line the gate of the MOSFET should get disabled thus both supply lines would get separated.

Like in the following diagram:
https://sketch.io/render/sketch559e419d99999.png

Usually R1 / R2 build a resistive divider - can be 1:1. Thus the gate of the MOSFET T1 is below VDD which will make it conductive. You will have 3.7V at OUT. When you apply the +5V the gate of T1 it will get pulled above 3.7V and the T1 will block.

But I do not really know how you would have to apply the +5 to OUT then. You can not simply wire it there because every MOSFET contains a weak internal parasitric diode (shown in dots) which would apply the +5V to your 3.7V supply.

So with the shown circuitry you can apply 3.7V to OUT only if +5V is absent. But you can not connect both supplies. What could help here is an analog switch like those ones: http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74LVC1G3157.pdf

You could exchange the MOSFET in my circuit with such an analog switch. The even show a defined break-before-make behaviour.

Another idea would be to use enhancement type devices (JFET/MOSFET) which are conducting when no voltage is applied to the gate - when a voltage higher than 3.7 V gets applied the difference (1.3V) could get applied to the gate and they will become blocking.

There are quite some possibilities ... but finally I think you will have to experiment :)

If you are to connect some kind of self-made modules I would suggest a simple jumper. You will simply have to know what you are doing when connecting two modules.